# Hibernate multiple entity join problem, additional queries are generated

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, join, hibernate-criteria

There is N+1 problem, while joining multiple entities with @OneToOne Association (Hibernate 5.2)

```
     @Entity
     @Table(name = "COMMON_CARDS")
     public class CommonCards {

       @Id
       @Column(name = "card_number")
       private String card_number;
       @Column(name = "card_id")
       private String card_id;
       @Column(name = "bank_C")
       private String bankC;
       @Column(name = "centre_Id")
       private String centreId;
       @Column(name = "bank_Id")
       private String bankId;
       @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
       @JoinColumn(name = "CARD_NUMBER")
       private StipCards stipCards;

       @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
       @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
       @JoinColumn(name = "CARD_NUMBER", insertable = false, updatable = false)
       private CardsExceptions cardsExceptions;

     /*getters and setters*/
     }

     @Entity
     @Table(name = "STIP_CARDS")
     public class StipCards {
       @Id
       @Column(name = "CARD_NUMBER")
       private String card_number;
       @Column(name = "CENTRE_ID")
       private String CENTRE_ID;
       @Column(name = "Expiry_Date_1")
       private String expriryDate1;
       @Column(name = "Expiry_Date_2")
       private String expriryDate2;
       @Column(name = "stat_code_1")
       private String statCode1;
       @Column(name = "stat_code_2")
       private String statCode2;

     /*getters and setters*/
     }

         @Entity
         @Table(name = "CARDS_EXCEPTIONS")
         public class CardsExceptions {
           @Id
           @Column(name = "CARD_NUMBER")
           private String cardNumber;
           @Column(name = "ACTION_CODE")
           private String actionCode;

         /*getters and setters*/
}
```

here is implementation code to get list of records from database

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<CommonCards> criteria = builder.createQuery(CommonCards.class);
    Root<CommonCards> root = criteria.from(CommonCards.class);
    Join<Object, Object> joinStipCards = (Join<Object, Object>) root.fetch("stipCards", JoinType.INNER);
    Join<Object, Object> joinException = (Join<Object, Object>) root.fetch("cardsExceptions", JoinType.LEFT);

    Predicate predicate = builder.and(root.get("card_id").in(cardIds));
    predicate = builder.and(predicate, builder.and(builder.equal(joinStipCards.get("CENTRE_ID"), root.get("centreId"))));

    criteria.where(predicate);
    List<CommonCards> commonCards = session.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();

    for (CommonCards card : commonCards) {
      System.out.println(card.toString());
    }
```

This code generates two select statement

**FIRST SQL**

```
SELECT commoncard0_.card_number  AS card_number1_5_0_
      ,stipcards1_.CARD_NUMBER   AS CARD_NUMBER1_2_1_
      ,cardsexcep2_.CARD_NUMBER  AS CARD_NUMBER1_1_2_
      ,commoncard0_.bank_C       AS bank_C2_5_0_
      ,commoncard0_.bank_Id      AS bank_Id3_5_0_
      ,commoncard0_.card_id      AS card_id4_5_0_
      ,commoncard0_.CARD_NUMBER  AS CARD_NUMBER1_5_0_
      ,commoncard0_.centre_Id    AS centre_Id5_5_0_
      ,stipcards1_.CENTRE_ID     AS CENTRE_ID2_2_1_
      ,stipcards1_.Expiry_Date_1 AS Expiry_Date_3_2_1_
      ,stipcards1_.Expiry_Date_2 AS Expiry_Date_4_2_1_
      ,stipcards1_.stat_code_1   AS stat_code_5_2_1_
      ,stipcards1_.stat_code_2   AS stat_code_6_2_1_
      ,cardsexcep2_.ACTION_CODE  AS ACTION_CODE2_1_2_
  FROM COMMON_CARDS commoncard0_
 INNER JOIN STIP_CARDS stipcards1_
    ON commoncard0_.CARD_NUMBER = stipcards1_.CARD_NUMBER
  LEFT OUTER JOIN CARDS_EXCEPTIONS cardsexcep2_
    ON commoncard0_.CARD_NUMBER = cardsexcep2_.CARD_NUMBER
 WHERE (commoncard0_.card_id IN (?,?,?,?))
   AND stipcards1_.CENTRE_ID = commoncard0_.centre_Id
```

**SECOD SQL**

This second statement is generated when some record exists in to first 2 table but does not exists in to cards_exception table(entity).
number of query execution depends on how many record was not found in to cards_exceptions table.

```
SELECT cardsexcep0_.CARD_NUMBER AS CARD_NUMBER1_1_0_
      ,cardsexcep0_.ACTION_CODE AS ACTION_CODE2_1_0_
  FROM CARDS_EXCEPTIONS cardsexcep0_
 WHERE cardsexcep0_.CARD_NUMBER = ?
```

Please explain why Hibernate Generates additional query and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you verbose what you are trying to receive? For what are you creating the variable joinException? It is not used in the code.

Comment: I'm trying to receive records from database. problem is that, there is exampe 100 record in CommonCards and StipCards entity, but there is only 70 related record in CardsException Entity. then hibernate generates 30  "Second SQL" query for each card which is not in CardsException.   root.fetch("cardsExceptions", JoinType.LEFT); is used.

Comment: So, you are trying to receive a list of CommonCards where card_id is in given list cardIds, but only those of them that have CENTRE_ID the same as the CommonCards.centreId (this is the inner join), and for those you receive you would like also joinfetch the list of the cardsExceptions (without additional condition), so that no additional requests will be executed for them. Try to change: Join<Object, Object> joinException = (Join<Object, Object>) root.fetch("cardsExceptions", JoinType.LEFT); by root.fetch(CommonCards_.cardsExceptions, JoinType.LEFT); CommonCards_ is a metamodel of CommonCards.